# Insert a line from a file in excel

Tags: excel

I have a line like this in txt file:

```
1, yous, 115 bd xxx, football
```

Every field is seperated by a comma.I want to insert this line in a excel file which has exactly the same number of columns (4), i tried copy/paste but it was inserted in just one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pasting the text, select the cell, then use Text to Columns on the Data ribbon. Select **Delimited** > Next > tick **Comma** and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

You can use this technique for a single cell, or for many cells at the same time. If your data is in a text file, you can also invoke the Text to Column wizard from an empty sheet by clicking Data > From Text and select the file.

If the text is a .CSV file, you can open the CSV file with Excel and the commas will automatically indicate new cells in Excel. (You can also double-click a .CSV file in Windows Explorer and it should open in Excel)

Comment: I added some more details to my post.

Comment: i try 3th option but it doesn't work. i put `1, yous, 115 bd xxx, football` in a csv file but excel didn't recognize the column automatically.

Comment: + 1 :) However I have voted this question to be moved to SU as it is offtopic :)